# Process enumeration in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mobile, adobe, air

Is there a way to check whether a process with a given process ID is alive in the system using actionscript? Which class in actionscript has functions to enumerate list of processes active in the system?

Comment: What kind of processes do you mean? Processes of underlying operating system or what? And what kind of app do you develop: in browser Flash app, AIR app or mobile AIR app?

Comment: I'm devloping a mobile AIR app. Using ANE, I'm spawning multiple  native processes. I store the process ID of each process which was launched. At some point, I want to check what all processes are alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NativeProcess` class ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) of AIR lets you execute a native process via the command line. Once it's started, you can query if it's still running.

I don't think there's anything though that lets you query other process IDs (that you didn't start). I'd imagine security issues are the reason.

Comment: So, no one will be able to write an air-app similar to task manager of Windows?

Comment: You could write one for apps that you spawn through AIR (I'm not sure if there's a limit), but not for the generic windows processes

Comment: @kiran, correct, you couldn't.  That is outside the scope of Air and is a lot more OS specific.  The purpose of air is to create a reusable front end client that is agnostic to the OS.